# Combining Flask with Nuxtjs for SSR

Tags: vue.js, flask, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am developing a universal app with separated frontend and backend using Flask as an API and Nuxtjs for frontend.
Before trying Nuxtjs, I was using only vuejs (SPA) but then I realized that it was not optimized for SEO. Anyways, I was able to use generated dist files when using build mode(static and index.html). And I was able to deal with it by using this code:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = "../frontend/dist")
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/static/js/<filename>')
def send_js(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/dist/static/js', filename)

@app.route('/static/css/<filename>')
def send_css(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/dist/static/css', filename)

@app.route('/static/fonts/<filename>')
def send_img(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/dist/static/fonts', filename)

@app.route('/static/img/<filename>')
def send_statics(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/dist/static/img', filename)

@app.route('/statics/icons/<filename>')
def send_icons(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/dist/static/statics/icons', filename)


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return render_template("index.html")
```

However, when I started using Nuxtjs, build mode generates different files (no index.html and no static folder) And I don't know how to deal with it. You can find what it generates in the screenshot below:
[generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP2ce.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your Nuxt app to a static website you must change this in your **nuxt.config.js** file:

```js
{
  target: 'static'
}
```

By default Nuxt generates all files into **/dist** folder, and when you set the static mode, dist folder looks like:

```
/dist
  /_nuxt       --- Core functionality: JS and CSS files go here
  /images      --- All images stored into /static/images folder
  /your-page-1 --- Contains one HTML file (If /pages/your-page-1.vue exists)
  index.html   --- Your main html file
  404.html     --- Default error page for 404
```

404 page is not generated by default, so if you want to generate it, you must set this config into **nuxt.config.js** file:

```js
{
  generate: {
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

If you need to rename generated files, add this config to nuxt.config.js file:

```js
{
  build: {
    filenames: {
      app: () => '[name].js',
      chunk: () => '[name].js',
      css: () => '[name].css',
      img: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
      font: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
      video: () => '[path][name].[ext]'
    }
  }
}
```